# Can I create a slot without creating a class?

Tags: c++, qt

Just a simple prog to illustrate the issue in a larger one. What I am trying to do is to create a function for signal/slot connection without using any classes. I am new to OOP and don't want to have to do with classes at the moment. So, I am creating a function before the `main` function and hope this will work... but it doesn't. The prog can be compiled and executed, but I get a notification: `Object::connect: No such slot QTextEdit::onClicked()`. I anticipate the issue can very easily be solved as it is rather a mistake of expression than of understanding, so thanks in advance for your help! :)

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtCore>

    void onClicked (QTextEdit text, QString a)
    {
        text.setText(a);
    }

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QApplication app(argc, argv);

        QWidget mw;
        mw.setWindowTitle("Main Window");
        mw.resize(400, 400);
        mw.show();

        QLabel label ("Enter something:", &mw);
        label.setAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter);
        label.show();

        QLineEdit line (&mw);
        line.show();

        QString a = line.text();

        QTextEdit text (&mw);
        text.show();

        QPushButton btn ("Convert", &mw);
        QObject::connect(
        &btn,
        SIGNAL(clicked()),
        &text,
        SLOT(onClicked()));
        btn.show();

        QVBoxLayout layout_mw;

        layout_mw.addWidget(&label);
        layout_mw.addWidget(&line);
        layout_mw.addWidget(&btn);
        layout_mw.addWidget(&text);

        mw.setLayout(&layout_mw);

        return app.exec();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read in the Qt documentation that:

> All classes that inherit from QObject or one of its subclasses (e.g.,
>   QWidget) can contain signals and slots.

So you can not define slots in main.cpp. You have two options. Either define a class derived from QObject and add your slot there or use Qt 5.* and connect your signal to a lambda using the new syntax for connections.

Comment: Hi @Nejat, first of all I'd like to thank you for helping me since yesterday :D your answers have always been helpful, and yesterday I was struggling really hard to create a class, I seemed to do everything correctly but what I got was an error "invalid declaration of member template in local class"... then I gave up and tried to "cheat" by creating a slot outside a class...as you say it won't work. Could you please help me a little bit creating a class, I have my code already but I don't understand this template stuff... I could send the code to you.

Comment: well I decided to move to Qt 5 and use a lambda :) Are there any useful tips for changing to Qt 5, e.g. I should change some headers?..

Answer (score 6):

well,it is true that slots are only available in QObjects BUT you can for sure connect signals to lambdas too :)

so, in this case you can uses the helpful lambda and omit the custom function

> void onClicked (QTextEdit text, QString a) :

like

```
QObject::connect(&btn, &QPushButton::clicked,
    [](QTextEdit te, QString s){qDebug() << "am in...";});
```

Comment: can I do it in Qt 4.8, too? hope so... :)

Comment: @val I'm sorry but this feature is Qt5+ only: https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax

Comment: @cbuchart I knew that, nevermind :) I've already decided to move to Qt5, would you suggest a command for the bash (Ubuntu) to do it?

Comment: Probably more problems than benefits... change the project and fix the compilation issues. I haven't moved projects too big (most of them have started as Qt 5 from the very beginning), but in general I think most things will be related to deprecated methods... [here](https://wiki.qt.io/Transition_from_Qt_4.x_to_Qt5) a quick guide for the transition

Comment: @cbuchart you're absolutely right! wanted to change to Qt 5 right now but as I saw there is a whole lot of problems using cyrillic encoding there as a very helpful method is totally gone, so I must stay on Qt 4... And that means for me, I cannot use lambda :( Will have to deal with classes...